# How to display multiple exceptions as a list?

Tags: php, exception, usability

We have an enviroment where exceptions are frequent, and a few can be thrown simultaneowsly.

We are trying to improve usability, so instead of printing each exception when it's catched, we want to store them and build a list at the end of the document.

After considering some solutions -from jQuery cloning to a global `$exceptions[]` array, including CSS pure replacement- we can't find out what would be the better practice.

So the question is: **is there any trustworthy and documented way to collect multiple exceptions and display them together?**

**EDIT: Context**
Exceptions are thrown when writing templates for a CMS (mainly, retrieving "content" that returns `NULL`). There are lots of these errors when a designer starts developing. We don't want to prevent the template to be previewed, but in the other hand we want to notify what should be fixed.

Comment: What baffles me is what you expect: An exception is a great reason NOT to continue your script. Why do you collect them? Fix the first exception and work your way up until the script behaves as it should.

Comment: Added a little context to avoid "baffling" ;)

Comment: "we want to notify what should be fixed" Isn't that a purpose for an error log?

Comment: Maybe @feeela, but we need to give visual feedback to the designer. We're not discussing the UX dimension of the problem, we are trying to implement that UX efficiently.

Comment: Perhaps it's a multiple validation. I have a the same problem, let me give you an example. we have a data grid with editable rows. Now your validation happens after submitting. During the process some of the rows are successfully added and some were not. How would you notify the user of the validation.